# PHP call function on object only on condition in one line

Tags: php

in PHP I want to call a function on an object:

```
$something->function1()->function2();
```

And now `function2` should only be called when the variable `$decision` is `true`.

So something like:

```
$something->function1();
if($decision)
    $something->function2();
```

But I am curiouse if this will be possible in only one line. So all in all more beautiful.

### Context:

In PHP doctrine I have a QueryBuilder and there is a `where` clause, that should only be appended when the Variable `$decision` is `true`.
The idea: select something, but when decision is true, also add a second WHERE section.

```
[...]
->withQueryBuilder(
    $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder()
        ->select('s')
        ->from(SomeEntity::class, 's')
        ->where('s.public = true')
        ->whereAnd('s.decision = true')
)
[...]
```

And here the `->whereAnd('e.decision = true')` should only be executed, when the `$decision` is `true`.
The problem here is, that I can not simply add a if statement because the function `withQueryBuilde()` only allowes one parameter.

### UPDATE

I also tried something like this:

```
[...]
->withQueryBuilder(
    function(){
        return $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder()
            ->select('s')
            ->from(SomeEntity::class, 's')
            ->where('s.public = true')
            ->whereAnd('s.decision = true');
    }
)
[...]
```

But `Call to undefined method Closure::expr()`

Comment: I think you are trying to oversimplify things. From your description you need more code than this. You can't really do chaining with conditionals.

Comment: Regarding _"I can not simply add a if statement because the function withQueryBuilde() only allowes one parameter."_, wouldn't you be adding the if statement inside the function that is the one parameter? Or did I misunderstand what you meant there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, i don't think there is any sense in what you want to do, but if you really want, there may by solution if you can add to QueryBuilder a function that do nothing. Then you can

```
$this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder()
        ->select('s')
        ->from(SomeEntity::class, 's')
        ->where('s.public = true')
        ->{$decision ? 'whereAnd' : 'doNothing'}('s.decision = true');
```

You can also modify argument, to make no effect on query

```
->whereAnd($decision ? 's.decision = true' : 'true=true' )
```

Still, you should simply use normal if, unless you make a bet that you can do this in one line.

Comment: I was curiouse of learning something. And that this is also possible with ternary is cool. Thanks.